# Different DataContext in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

My Code looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MTMngRoot.MTManager.MTCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="Name" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Name" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DefaultCT}" Grid.Column="1">
                    <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This code works correctly. But now I want to bind the `Itemssource` from the `ComboBox`. My Problem is now, the `Path` of the `Items` that should be bind to the `ComboBox` is completly different. The `Path` looks like this: `CTMngRoot.CTManager.CTCollection.Name`. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You walk up to the control with the correct `DataContext` in these cases.

```
{Binding DataContext.CTMngRoot.CTManager.CTCollection,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have some problems with it. I forgot to write that I   set the 'Main'-Datacontext in the `xaml.cs` file (`this.DataContext = this.MngRoot;`). Inside this class are the two instance (`CTMngRoot` and `MTMngRoot`). 

Now I added your code to my `ComboBox`. It looks like this now: 
`<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding Path=CTMngRoot.CTManager, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CTCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DefaultCT}" Grid.Column="1"/>`

It don't work like this.

Comment: You did not properly transfer my solution. `RelativeSource` makes your binding source a control, thus you need to bind  to `DataContext` at the beginning of the `Path` to access the data. Also, binding the `ComboBox.DataContext` is a bad idea, you should directly bind the `ItemsSource` like i have shown, otherwise you will have trouble binding the `SelectedItem`.

Comment: Thanks! Now it worked. You did a mistake. You wrote `{Binding DataComtext.CTMngRoot...` I think it must be called `{Binding DataContext.CTMngRoot...`. 
Thanks agaiN!